# Maximum (a[j] - a[i]) * min(b[j], b[i]) such that j > i?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

Given two arrays `a` and `b` of equal length `n` having positive integer values, I want an algorithm to find the maximum quantity of `(a[j] - a[i]) * min(b[j], b[i])` such that `0 <= i < j < n`. This problem is somewhat related to [Maximum difference between two elements such that larger element appears after the smaller number](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-difference-between-two-elements/) but it also introduces a new restriction of an array `b`. This algorithm cannot be used by creating a new array `c` so that for every `i`: `c[i] = a[i] * b[i]` due to the `min()` restriction.
So I am wondering if this problem can be solved in linear `O(n)` or maybe `O(n*logn)` or it can be proved that is solvable only in `O(n^2)`. Any hint would be great.

Comment: Can you please link to where you found this problem?

Comment: @IVlad I didn't find it somewhere. It came up from a problem of optimizing transactions on stock market where the ```a``` array represents the prices of the stock and the ```b``` array represents a restriction of how many stocks can be bought and sold on day ```i``` and ```j``` respectively.

Comment: Can you also post the full original problem please? There might be an easier solution not involving this formula.

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed `j`, we have two cases for `i < j`:

**1. `b[i] < b[j]`**

We must find the minimum `a[i]` such that this condition holds.

We can use a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) data structure `d1` for this, in which `a[d1.front]` will always be this minimum - so we keep `d1` sorted such that the condition holds and it contains the minimum in `a`. Note that `d1` only contains positions, not values.

For each `j` (you might need some sanity checks for whether `d1` is empty in your language of choice):

```
while a[j] <= a[d1.back]:
    d.pop_back()
while b[d1.front] >= b[j]:
    d.pop_front()
quantity1 = (a[j] - a[d1.front]) * b[d1.front]
d1.push_back(j)
```

**2. `b[i] >= b[j]`**

Do the same thing with a `d2` to compute `quantity2`. Then, take the max of the two qantities and compare this max to a global max.

This might seem like `O(n^2)` because you will still have nested loops, however it is `O(n)`: notice that each value will enter and leave each deque at most once.